# Selecting a specific date with a PL/SQL statement

Tags: oracle, plsql

I need to display Customer, Bill Date, Description and Vehicle from the following tables:
CUSTOMER, BILLING, DELIVERY_ITEMS, VEHICLE

I do not understand the error that I get when I try to compile the code.

Here's my code:

```
 DECLARE
  FNAME VARCHAR2(20);
  SNAME VARCHAR2(20);
  BILLDATE DATE;
  DESCRIP VARCHAR2(50);
  VEH VARCHAR2(30);

  BEGIN
  SELECT FIRST_NAME, SURNAME, BILL_DATE, DESCRIPTION, VEHICLE_TYPE
  INTO FNAME, SNAME, BILLDATE, DESCRIP, VEH
   FROM CUSTOMER, BILLING, DELIVERY_ITEMS, VEHICLE
   WHERE BILL_DATE ('10/NOV/16', 'DD/MM/YY')<DATE;


    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('CUSTOMER : '|| FNAME  ||','|| SNAME);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('BILL DATE: '|| BILLDATE);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('DESCRIPTION: '|| DESCRIP);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('VEHICLE: '|| VEH);
    END;
/
```

I am getting the following error report:

```
Error report -
ORA-06550: line 12, column 51:
PL/SQL: ORA-00936: missing expression
ORA-06550: line 9, column 7:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: which database you are using mysql/mssql/oracle?

Comment: The error message says you are using Oracle, so please remove wrong tags; what do you need to do with `WHERE BILL_DATE ('10/NOV/16', 'DD/MM/YY')<DATE`?

Comment: @ Zafar Malik - Oracle SQL Developer with Oracle 11G as I have to use this for college. @Aleksej - Here is the question: Create a PL/SQL query that will display the combined customer name, bill date, description of the 
delivery and the vehicle that will be used for the delivery. In your query only display the deliveries 
taking place on the 10 November 2016.

Comment: Did you mean `WHERE TO_DATE('10/NOV/16', 'DD/MM/YY') < BILL_DATE ;`

Comment: @Praveen - I just tried that but now I get this: Error report -
ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows
ORA-06512: at line 9
01422. 00000 -  "exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows"
*Cause:    The number specified in exact fetch is less than the rows returned.
*Action:   Rewrite the query or change number of rows requested

Comment: You need to put it inside a loop and you may also want to join those tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very first question that has to be asked is are you expecting singular resultset or multi row resultset?
If singular result set is expected then the WHERE condition has to be modifed as illustrated below

```
DECLARE
  FNAME    VARCHAR2(20);
  SNAME    VARCHAR2(20);
  BILLDATE DATE;
  DESCRIP  VARCHAR2(50);
  VEH      VARCHAR2(30);
BEGIN
  SELECT FIRST_NAME,
    SURNAME,
    BILL_DATE,
    DESCRIPTION,
    VEHICLE_TYPE
  INTO FNAME,
    SNAME,
    BILLDATE,
    DESCRIP,
    VEH
  FROM CUSTOMER,
    BILLING,
    DELIVERY_ITEMS,
    VEHICLE
  WHERE BILL_DATE = TO_DATE('10/NOV/16', 'DD/MON/YY');
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('CUSTOMER : '|| FNAME ||','|| SNAME);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('BILL DATE: '|| BILLDATE);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('DESCRIPTION: '|| DESCRIP);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('VEHICLE: '|| VEH);
END;
```

And if you are expexcting multiple results then should always go with BULK Collect.
In this case as just for illustration purpose i am using row by row processing.
Hope this helps

```
BEGIN
  FOR I IN
  (SELECT FIRST_NAME,
    SURNAME,
    BILL_DATE,
    DESCRIPTION,
    VEHICLE_TYPE
  FROM CUSTOMER,
    BILLING,
    DELIVERY_ITEMS,
    VEHICLE
  WHERE BILL_DATE = TO_DATE('10/NOV/16', 'DD/MON/YY')
  )
  LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('CUSTOMER : '|| I.FIRST_NAME ||','|| I.SURNAME);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('BILL DATE: '|| I.BILL_DATE);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('DESCRIPTION: '|| I.DESCRIPTION);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('VEHICLE: '|| I.VEHICLE_TYPE);
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: Thank you for this, it helped me! I managed to use this and I've also made some changes to my code to get the desired output.

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem in

```
WHERE BILL_DATE ('10/NOV/16', 'DD/MM/YY')<DATE
```

Assuming that you have a date field in one of your tables (let's name it DATE_FIELD), you can apply a condition (= for example) on it with:

```
WHERE DATE_FIELD = TO_DATE ('10/NOV/16', 'DD/MM/YY')
```

or, given that you have a variable `BILL_DATE`, you can do:

```
WHERE DATE_FIELD = BILL_DATE
```

Of course, before using the variable `BILL_DATE`, you need an assignment, for example:

```
BILL_DATE := TO_DATE ('10/NOV/16', 'DD/MM/YY')
```

Besides, if your query returns more than one row, you have to choose:

1. limit your dataset with some condition, or simply add `AND ROWNUM = 1` for a test
2. use a cursor and loop through it (see an [example](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/loops/cursor_for.php))
3. use a BULK COLLECT ( see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36037941/oracle-sql-declaring-variables-to-use-in-queries-subqueries/36038691#36038691) for example)

Answer (score 0):

Try `for loop` if your `select` statement returns more than one row

```
BEGIN
    for i in (
         SELECT FIRST_NAME, SURNAME, BILL_DATE, DESCRIPTION, VEHICLE_TYPE
         FROM CUSTOMER, BILLING, DELIVERY_ITEMS, VEHICLE
         WHERE TO_DATE('10/NOV/16', 'DD/MM/YY') < BILL_DATE
    ) loop
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('CUSTOMER : '|| i.FIRST_NAME  ||','|| i.SURNAME);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('BILL DATE: '|| i.BILL_DATE);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('DESCRIPTION: '|| i.DESCRIPTION);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('VEHICLE: '|| i.VEHICLE_TYPE);
    end loop;
END;
/
```